# Is there a direct way to combine setters for multiple record fields to a single setter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, arrows, lenses

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data Foo = Foo {
    _bar, _baz :: Int
   }
makeLenses ''Foo
```

Now if I want to modify both int fields, I can do

```
barbaz :: Setter' Foo Int
barbaz = sets $ \foo f -> foo & bar %~ f
                              & baz %~ f
```

but this seems like a pretty ugly manual way to do it.

Can the same be achieved directly with lens/arrow combinators?

Comment: This seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528119/combining-lenses

Comment: Were you using a tuple instead of `Foo`, you could do something like [`(1,2) & both .~ 10`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:both) to set both elements of the tuple to `10`.

Comment: You can combine setters like `bar %~ f` using [compose](https://wiki.haskell.org/Compose)

Answer (score 2):

*lens* doesn't a ready-made combinator for that, presumably beacuase you can get illegal setters (or lenses) if the focuses of the components overlap.

```
data Trio a = Trio a a a
    deriving (Show)

oneTwo :: Setter' (Trio a) (a, a)
oneTwo = sets $ \f (Trio x y z) -> let (x', y') = f (x, y) in Trio x' y' z

twoThree :: Setter' (Trio a) (a, a)
twoThree = sets $ \f (Trio x y z) -> let (y', z') = f (y, z) in Trio x y' z'

cheating :: Setter' (Trio a) (a, a)
cheating = sets $ \f x -> x & oneTwo %~ f & twoThree %~ f
```

```
GHCi> Trio 1 1 1 & cheating %~ bimap (2*) (2*) & cheating %~ bimap (3+) (3+)
Trio 5 10 5
GHCi> Trio 1 1 1 & cheating %~ (bimap (2*) (2*) <&> bimap (3+) (3+))
Trio 5 13 5
```

In your case, the nicest alternative to building the setter/traversal by hand (as you [and Cristoph Hegemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787247/2751851) are doing) seems to be `liftA2 (>=>) :: ASetter' s a -> ASetter' s a -> ASetter' s a`, as suggested elsewhere by [bennofs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529470/2751851) (thanks Shersh for the link). If you happen to have a lens to a homogeneous pair (or some other `Bitraversable`) lying around, you can get the traversal out of it with `both`:

```
data Foo = Foo
   { _bar, _baz :: Int
   } deriving (Show)
makeLenses ''Foo

barBaz :: Iso' Foo (Int, Int)
barBaz = iso ((,) <$> view bar <*> view baz) (Foo <$> fst <*> snd)
```

```
GHCi> Foo 1 2 & barBaz . both %~ (2*)
Foo {_bar = 2, _baz = 4}
```

Yet another possibility is exploiting [`Data.Data.Lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/src/Data.Data.Lens.html) to get a traversal of all fields of a certain type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Data.Lens
import Data.Data

data Foo = Foo
   { _bar, _baz :: Int
   } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)
makeLenses ''Foo

barBaz :: Traversal' Foo Int
barBaz = template
```

```
GHCi> Foo 1 2 & barBaz %~ (2*)
Foo {_bar = 2, _baz = 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before and have a solution that works for two lenses by combining them into a Traversal:

```
fields2 :: Lens' s a -> Lens' s a -> Traversal' s a
fields2 f1 f2 f s = (\v1 v2 -> s & f1 .~ v1 & f2 .~ v2) <$> f (s ^. f1) <*> f (s ^. f2)

barbaz = fields2 bar baz
```

This can than be used like:

```
foo & barbaz %~ f
```

It's a little dirty and doesn't scale but it works for me :D If someone posts a nicer answer I'll be very happy!